# Webtrends Issue - Adding data to links

Tags: hyperlink, webtrends

At my company, we are using webtrends.  The stats guy is telling me that we need to append &WT.svl=UniqueDescOfLink to every single link on our site.

I don't know much about webtrends, bit I am sure someone here does.  How would you avoid concatenating every single link on a website with this webtrends tagging data?  Rewrite all of the links with Java?

I am coming from the google analytic's side of things where I simply add a javascript include on the bottom of the page.

How does everyone else handle this?  The idea I believe is to see how hot each link is on a page.

Answer (score 0):

WT.svl is just needed for unify the Links in SmartView. E.g. you have to links to the same site and you want to know if the visitors use link1 or link2.

For basic SmartView, you just need to install the plugin in your IE and enable Basic SmartViewing in the WebTrends Profile. You can also create a specific profile just for SmartView.